# Best way to learn Magento 2 step by step Guide?

Tags: magento2

Best way to learn Magento 2 step by step Guide ?

Can anyoune suggest me best Magento 2 tutorial .

Step by step guide .

please check : https://onlineinformationstations.com/best-way-to-learn-magento-2-from-scratch/

Answer (score 5):

refer to this pdf. this is best so far
https://share.nxtcloud.net/mirror/WebDev/Magento/Magento%202%20Developers%20Guide.pdf

Comment: any other suggestion ?

Comment: u can refer module development series by mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)

Comment: any new pdf for customization or KO related?

Comment: https://share.nxtcloud.net/mirror/WebDev/Magento/Magento%202%20Developers%20Guide.pdf   link not working